# Android Dev - Spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I am stuck in a situation. I'm trying to use spinners in order for users to select locations. I am populating the spinners via sqlite. The idea is sometimes there is a country, province, city and sub-areas, however any field can be blank (if not populated in database).

I would like the spinners to be "hidden" if they do not have the values stored in the database. However, only the "next step down" (ex: country to province) is hidden and not all the "other steps down" (city and sub-area)

I hope I am being clear enough, if not I can clarify.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) 
{

    if (parent.getId() == R.id.spinner_query_country)
    {
        country.selected = (class_location)country.spinner.getSelectedItem();
        get_province();
    }
    else if (parent.getId() == R.id.spinner_query_province)
    {
        province.selected = (class_location)province.spinner.getSelectedItem();
        get_city();
    }
    else if (parent.getId() == R.id.spinner_query_city)
    {
        city.selected = (class_location)city.spinner.getSelectedItem();
        get_sub_area();
    }
    else if (parent.getId() == R.id.spinner_query_sub_area)
    {
        sub_area.selected = (class_location)sub_area.spinner.getSelectedItem();
    }

}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

void get_country()
{       
    make_spinner(country, db.getAll("SELECT * FROM country"));
}
void get_province()
{   
    make_spinner(province, db.getAll("SELECT * FROM province WHERE country_key=" + country.selected._key));
}
void get_city()
{   
    make_spinner(city, db.getAll("SELECT * FROM city WHERE province_key=" + province.selected._key));
}
void get_sub_area()
{   
    make_spinner(sub_area, db.getAll("SELECT * FROM sub_area WHERE city_key=" + city.selected._key));
}


void make_spinner(_structure structure, List<class_location> location_list)
{
    if (location_list.size() > 0)
    {
        class_location location_array[] = location_list.toArray(new class_location[location_list.size()]);

        ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, location_array);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        structure.spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        structure.spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        structure.textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        structure.spinner.setAdapter(null);
        structure.spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        structure.textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are hidding only one spinner, not all of them simply because you are setting the visibility at `make_spinner()` and you only check one step down on your `onItemSelected`(if else strict). To make it clear, your code sets the visibility or invisibility of the components on a method that is never called for the "others steps down".

P.S.: Your code is kinda messy and do not follow the conventions or guidelines of Android. This is bad. Try to checkout some guidelines, help your collaborators :)